Calling api call using riverpod onClick Listener in flutter
I'm trying to call the same api call using dio and listen to that api call using riverpod , but the issue is that when i call the api call in the build function , it works but when i call the same api call with a different parametre , it does not refresh ui when called , tried ref.invalidate() and ref.read() but no luck , i would be happy to get some help , thank you .

This is how i call api in the build function


var data = ref.watch(getAllProductsProvider(Utils.categoriesNames[0].toLowerCase()));



This is my where i call api onClick


class HomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _HomePageState();

}

class _HomePageState extends ConsumerState<HomePage> {

  late List<String> categoriesNamesY;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();
  int pageIndex = 0;
  int selectedCategory = 0;
  late Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    categoriesNamesY = [
      LocaleKeys.electronics.tr(),
      LocaleKeys.jewelery.tr(),
      LocaleKeys.men.tr(),
      LocaleKeys.welcome.tr()
    ];
    swipeImages();
  }

  void swipeImages() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (pageIndex == 3) {
          pageIndex = 0;
        } else {
          pageIndex++;
        }
        _pageController.animateToPage(
          pageIndex,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var data = ref.watch(getAllProductsProvider(Utils.categoriesNames[1].toLowerCase()));
    return  SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(child: Text(LocaleKeys.welcome.tr(),style: AppFonts.getFont().copyWith(fontSize: 25),),),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5,),
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                      Get.toNamed(AppRouting.cartPage);
                    }, icon: const Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart,size: 25,)),
                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                      Get.toNamed(AppRouting.settingsRoute);
                    }, icon: const Icon(Icons.settings_applications,size: 25,))
                  ],
                ),
                const Divider(),
                const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                buildCarousel(context),
                const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                buildCards(context),
                const SizedBox(height: 30,),
                data.when(
                data: (product) {
          return GridView.count(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
            children: List.generate(product?.length ?? 0, (index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  var args = {
                    'value': product[index]!.id.toString(),
                  };
                  Get.toNamed(AppRouting.detailsRoute, arguments: args);
                },
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Image.network(
                          product![index]!.image,
                          height: 120,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        child: Text(
                          product[index]!.title,
                          style: AppFonts.getFont().copyWith(fontSize: 18),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        child: Text(
                          product[index]!.category,
                          style: AppFonts.getFont().copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        child: Text(
                          '\$${product[index]!.price}',
                          style: AppFonts.getFont().copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          );
        },
                  error: (object, stack) {
          return SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
            child: Center(child: Text(object.toString())),
          );
        },
                loading: () {
          return SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
            child: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.orange),
            ),
          );
        },)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget buildCarousel(BuildContext context){
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
      ),
      child: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: (index){
          setState(() {
            pageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        children: List.generate(Utils.banners.length, (index){
          return Stack(
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                child: Image.asset(Utils.banners[index],fit: BoxFit.cover,),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: List.generate(4, (index){
                      return Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: pageIndex == index ?  Colors.orange : Colors.white
                        ),
                      );
                    })),
              )
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget buildCards(BuildContext context){
    return SizedBox(
      height: 120,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: Utils.categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: (){

              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: Utils.categoriesNames[index].toLowerCase());

              setState(() {
                selectedCategory = index;
              });

              ref.read(getAllProductsProvider(Utils.categoriesNames[index].toLowerCase()));

            },
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.grey.shade100,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                side: BorderSide(
                  color: selectedCategory == index ? Colors.orange : Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,right: 15,top: 10,bottom: 10),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      Utils.categories[index],
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Text(
                      categoriesNamesY[index],
                      style: AppFonts.getFont().copyWith(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}




It seems like you are invalidating the provider for a specific parameter only.
The example below is from the riverpod documentation regarding invalidating a provider which receives parameters.
void onTap() {
  // Invalidate all possible parameter combinations of this provider.
  ref.invalidate(labelProvider);
  // Invalidate a specific combination only
  ref.invalidate(labelProvider('John'));
}


Thank you for your answer but still not working  , let me add all code and please take another look
